# Fix Conky widgets, not loading

Tags: kali-linux, conky

Recent system updates have broken Conky manager, well it hasn't been updated on Github 4-5 years, looks abandoned but still maybe anyone knows how to fix it. It happened with the latest updates on Kali and Arch too.

Here's Conky clock code:

```
use_xft yes
xftfont 123:size=8
xftalpha 0.1
update_interval 1
total_run_times 0

own_window yes
own_window_type normal
own_window_transparent no
own_window_hints undecorated,below,sticky,skip_taskbar,skip_pager
own_window_colour 000000
own_window_argb_visual yes
own_window_argb_value 0

double_buffer yes
#minimum_size 250 5
#maximum_width 500
draw_shades no
draw_outline no
draw_borders no
draw_graph_borders no
default_color white
default_shade_color red
default_outline_color green
alignment top_left
gap_x 100
gap_y 30
no_buffers yes
uppercase no
cpu_avg_samples 2
net_avg_samples 1
override_utf8_locale yes
use_spacer yes


minimum_size 0 0
TEXT
${voffset 10}${color EAEAEA}${font GE Inspira:pixelsize=80}${time %I:%M}${font}${voffset -72}${offset 10}${color FFA300}${font GE Inspira:pixelsize=42}${time %d} ${voffset -15}${color EAEAEA}${font GE Inspira:pixelsize=22}${time  %B} ${time %Y}${font}${voffset 24}${font GE Inspira:pixelsize=46}${offset -148}${time %A}${font}
${voffset 1}${offset 12}${font Ubuntu:pixelsize=12}${offset 0}${color FFA300}RAM ${offset 9}$color$mem / $memmax${offset 25}${color FFA300}CPU ${offset 9}$color${cpu cpu0}%
```

Running `conky -c ~/.conky/Gotham/Gotham` gives this output:

```
conky: Syntax error (Gotham:1: syntax error near 'yes') while reading config file. 
conky: Assuming it's in old syntax and attempting conversion.
conky: [string "..."]:159: attempt to call a nil value (global 'loadstring')
```

Comment: Fedora's been swept up in this as well, as of the new Fedora 33 release.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your config file needs to be updated to the latest version using Lua syntax. The wiki in the conky GitHub repository provides [detailed configuration information](https://github.com/brndnmtthws/conky/wiki/Configurations).

Comment: Thank you for the hint!